# How to change a color of a button by click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to  change the color of a button on click
I used this code but it does not work

```
onclick => myFunction();
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('#"+buttonId+"').style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: First of all, you do not need +buttonId+ because you are already inside of JS code.
Next, here is an example https://codepen.io/chionae/pen/xzOWvM

Comment: Leave out the # and you probably want to set the background-color instead of color e.g. document.getElementById('buttonId').style.backgroundColor = "red";

Comment: When you use the standard DOM routines as you are with getElementById, you can loose the "#" prefix, it is not required.  Also get into the habit of checking the return from getElementById before use, in this case the return will be "undefined" and you would see that if you check.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(buttonId).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.style.color = "red";
});
```

addEventListerner is a better practice than using event attributes in HTML, i advise you to try with it (either if you can't use it in your situation)
Also in getElementById you can't use the # caracter as CSS

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event

Also if you want to change the color button and not only the text color, the property "color" will not be the good one, but as we don't know how your button is made, we can't really help you on this side

Answer (score 0):

I think `buttonId`is undefined or wrong.

Try this:

```
onclick => myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    var buttonId = 'myButton';
    document.getElementById(buttonId).style.color = "red";
}
```

and in the HTML:

```
<button id="myButton">hello I am the button</button>
```

Comment: Don't use the # in the getElementById, and you don't closed the quote by opening double quote

document.getElementById(buttonId) would be better

Comment: Also he asks to change the button color. Currently you're changing the text color.

Comment: @Mick yes but without showing how is made his button, it's difficult to help on this side

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('myButton').style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" onClick="myFunction()">Change Color</button>
```

Comment: addEventListener would be better than an event attribute in my opinion

Comment: Amram asks to change the button color. You're changing the text color of the button.

Comment: @Mick yes but without showing how is made his button, it's difficult to help on this side

Comment: Good catch, @Mick. I think just about all of us missed that detail somehow. I guess we were all focused on the code he provided.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const changeColor = ()=>{
  const button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.style.color = 'red'
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="changeColor()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, The Mozilla Developer Network is a great resource for DOM manipulation as can be seen here. The following is a link to the MDN site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Here is an example using the addeventlistener method from the MDN site.

```
const buttonElement = document.getElementById('btn');
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

First, store the id of the element that will contain the event,'btn', in a variable, then call the addEventListener() method on the buttonElement variable. The first argument, 'click', defines the event type. The second argument is a function containing the event actions. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Another user pointed out you wanted to change the background color, not the text color. I misread your question, and I think most of the others did, too. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById(buttonId).style.color = "red";
}
```

- Don't use the # in the [document.getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)
- If you want to use # then try with [document.querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) or [document.querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To make it work properly you should pass de `this` object or the element id into your function. The code would be something like this:

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  buttonId = event.id;
  document.getElementById(buttonId).style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<button id='some-id' onclick=myFunction(this)>
  Button 1
</button>

<button id='other-id' onclick=myFunction(this)>
  Button 2
</button>
```

If you want to play around with this code you can go to: https://codepen.io/mjimenezmartin/pen/MWYzNrM?editors=1111
and try different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```js
ES5-

var buttonId = document.getElementById("buttonId") // Put your button Id

buttonId.addEventListener("click", function() {
   buttonId.style.color = "red";
})
```

```js
ES5+

const buttonId = document.getElementById("buttonId") // Put your button Id

buttonId.addEventListener("click", () => {
   buttonId.style.color = "red";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you should use only button ID without hash mark or quotes in the getElementById. The correct line should be as follows (of course buttonId must be initialized):

```
document.getElementById(buttonId).style.color = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you got many answers, will cover few extra things.

rather writing concatenation like this :

```
document.getElementById('#"+buttonId+"').style.color = "red";
```

you can use ES6 template literals :

```
document.getElementById(`${buttonId}`).style.color = "red";
```

And to keep things simpler, i would be solving it something like this:

```
const button = document.getElementById('id');
button.onclick = ()=> { .   // you can attach event as a property as well.
 button.style.color="red";
}
```

(you don't need to attach **onclick** attribute to your button markup this way makes mark-up much cleaner)

i am not suggesting it is the best way but it is much compact.

Comment: What is the difference between "getElementById(buttonId)" and "getElementById(`${buttonId}`)" ? Why use template litteral for that ?

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama here is the answer!  if you use "getElementById(buttonId)" then buttonId should be a variable which needs to hold buttonId value as a string. So that think about this is, we know we will be using buttonId only once to get the node element (button) so why to store it in a variable and waste memory. and template literal is the cleaner way to concatenate strings! please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: here with your template literal you use buttonId too, tha needs to hold buttonId value as a string too. Using template literal is a cleaner way to cancatenate strings but you don't here

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama you're right, last comment is all about a better way to concatenate. but the best is don't store it in a variable but if you're storing it then use template literal for concatenation.

Comment: and i concatenate in my answer for demonstration as the way question is asked.

Comment: yes for concatenation, but you don't do it in your exemple, you make concatenation with 2 blank strings, what is a waste of memory and performance (at this scale)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the colour &/or background colour is fairly straightforward using hardcoded values but does not lend itself well to re-use or template changes as you then need to edit the references to the hardcoded colours used. Both buttons below set the same colours but the second uses a `class` which can have different styles depending upon whatever stylesheet happens to declare that class. Neither button has an `inline` event handler - the preferred method is to assign event handlers externally which has similar benefits to using stylesheets ~ it keeps the HTML markup cleaner, allows for reuse and changes made in one place affect all instances if the js is within a separate file.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="bttn-x"]').onclick=function(e){
  this.style.color='red';
  this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
}

document.querySelector('[name="bttn-y"]').onclick=function(e){
  this.classList.toggle('fancy');
}
```

```css
[type='button']{
  padding:0.5rem;
  transition:all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.fancy{
  background:yellow;
  color:red;
  animation-name:fancybttn;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}
@keyframes fancybttn{
   from{transform:scale(1)}
   30%{transform:scale(1.1)}
   to{transform:scale(1)}
}
```

```html
<input name='bttn-x' type='button' value='Please click me' />

<input name='bttn-y' type='button' value='Or click me' />
```